# Virtual Host with WAMP

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I'm using Wamp 2.2, edited `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` edited this file to add VirtualHosts , but when I un-commented line in `httpd.conf` to include httpd-vhosts.conf file, after restarting Wamp doesn't starts. If I revert changes is works fine.

Any ideas why is this happening?

This is code I'm using in `httpd-vhost.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www" # change this line with your htdocs folder
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# WooCommerce Multisite
<VirtualHost dev.lo>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/dev"
    ServerName dev.lo
    ServerAlias dev.lo
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/dev">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

George

**Edit**

As **Andreas Hagen** suggested, I run Apache via httpd.exe.

First error was wrong parameter for `DocumentRoot`, as appears comment like was taken as second parameter, when `DocumentRoot` accepts only one.

Then I got warning: `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`. Did a quick search and found very helpful question - https://serverfault.com/questions/1405/apache-2-startup-warning-namevirtualhost-80-has-no-virtualhosts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably some bad config in vhosts file. Try to start apache from commandline so you get the error output. That will help you identify your problem.

Comment: Just run the exe file. Think it is named httpd.exe

Comment: Tried that, but httpd.exe closes as soon as I open it, so can't get error notices.

Comment: Run it in a terminal, meaning open cmd and enter path to httpd.exe

Answer (score 3):

Open your hosts file (`\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`).
Add this line to the bottom:

```
127.0.0.1        test
```

This will tell your computer that any url that contains test will be routed to 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Now open `httpd.conf` and add this to the very bottom of the file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80  
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/myfirstsite/"  
    ServerName testsite  
</VirtualHost>
```

Now restart apache and navigate to: http://test/ (you may have to restart your browser for the changes to take effect.)

Hope this works.

Comment: I've already edited hosts file for dev.lo - `127.0.0.1 dev.lo`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:/drive and choose wamp folder

and go to C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf and choose httpd.conf file.

Edit with notepad and go to 58 line number

change Listen 80 and replace Listen 8181 Save file and restart your Apache server

Now check url such like this localhost:8181

I have used this hop you will be success.