# Xampp based project for Wampserver

Tags: drupal-7, xampp, wampserver

I've been handed a project made within with xampp in mind, but it fails unlogically on my wampserver version. After heavy testing today it was concluded that my Wampserver simply did not "like" the project, thus creating unlogical errors which Xampp did not experience.

Now I'm pretty much required to have xampp open for this one project when I prefer wampserver and already have a lot of correctly working project there. I simply need to get this project to work on my wampserver aswell to make my life easier.

**So, the question** is regarding what differences are there between xampp and wampserver that could produce this error? I have tried using the same Apache and php version without any results.

The error is:

`EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property commerce_product. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 340 of C:\wamp\www\upplev\sites\all\modules\contrib\entity\includes\entity.wrapper.inc).`

And seems to be hopeless to solve. Have pretty much looked through the entire web regarding this issue, but none of the suggested solutions work for me. So I'm left with trying to simulate the behavior or xampp to my wampserver.

The project works on the xampp version 7.2 without any special settings.

Comment: Did you synchronize your new php.ini with the XAMPP one when you tried the same version of PHP on the WAMP server?

Comment: I've tried, but the apache won't reload. Not sure in it's due to the paths being different or files missing.

Comment: At least make certain your error reporting level is the same and that you have loaded all the same extensions. If Apache won't start with a given extension enabled, you may need to resolve a path issue or find a dll that is missing online. You can try running apache through the command line when it won't start to get more specific errors about what is failing.

Comment: An error message would help me a lot, currently I get nothing and have no idea why it doesn't work. Exactly how do you run apache through the command line? Is there something inside `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin` which I should run?

Comment: httpd.exe - see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819707/virtual-host-with-wamp

Comment: At least now I get the error `Cannot load C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/php5apache2_2.dll into server: %1 \
is not a valid Win32-program.`. Am trying to get wiser on that through google, but no luck yet.

Comment: Where did you get your WAMP stack? Try getting the newest available32-bit version on www.wampserver.com. Some of the modules used by PHP are not available in 64-bit so it may cause problems for you.